# mail command on macOS

Tags: terminal, email

I created a script to send an email before and after a command is run using the mail command this way:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "This is the body of the email" | mail -s "The command has started" user@example.com
/path/to/command_to_run
echo "This is the body of the email" | mail -s "The command has finished" user@example.com
```

But for some reason it's not working, BUT if I run that same command outside the script, it works.

The command shows as running, but neither of the 2 mail lines are working.

Any ideas what can be happening here?

Comment: What does not working mean? Does sending a mail work if you copy one of the echo/Mail pipes directly into bash?

Comment: The mail lines are not sending emails, even though they do work when run all by themselves.

Comment: Add `-v` to the mail command to get more info through the verbose mode. After having executed above commands, execute `mail` only on the command line to display the Mail Delivery Status Report. Add the results to your question.

Comment: I added -v and it told me "Mail Delivery Status Report will be mailed to <user>" so I checked /var/mail/user and all it said was that the email was relayed, but I don't see any email anywhere.